# Amazon Alexa isn't recognizing a number slot

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Lets say i have this in my schema:

```
 {
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "number",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
    }
  ],
  "intent": "PriceMyProduct"
}
```

And these utterances:

```
PriceMyProduct price of {number}
PriceMyProduct {number} price
```

In my lambda function I have this intent handler

```
'PriceMyProduct': function(){
        var itemNumber = this.event.request.slots.number.value;
         //DO STUFF
 }
```

The problem is that "itemNumber" never picks up the number of the product, so it is always undefined.

I have tried doing stuff like "price of 133202" or "133923 price", but the number value is never picked up. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing name of your slot from "number" to let say "priceValue". Something like this:

```
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "priceValue",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
    }
  ],
  "intent": "PriceMyProduct"
}
```

Then update utterances like this:

```
PriceMyProduct price of {priceValue}
PriceMyProduct {priceValue} price
```

And in lambda use the new name:

```
'PriceMyProduct': function(){
    var itemNumber = this.event.request.slots.priceValue.value;
     //DO STUFF
 }
```

Reason: number seems to be a reserved name

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. You were correct. This worked. Thank you very much!